# How to use PostgreSql hstore type with Fluent NHibarnate in c#

Tags: c#, postgresql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, hstore

I have a mvc application that uses fluent nhibarnate which connects to a postgresql database. I have trouble when i try to get hstore type from database. 
And i try to change the entity like

Entity

```
IDictionary<string,string> fields {get;set;}
```

Mapping

```
  Map(x=>x.fields).CustomSqlType("hstore");
```

Getting error like 
 
*Could not determine type for: System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2*

So what is the way to get a hstore type field from a postgresql database ?